# Can the await keyword result in parallel code?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

Suppose I have two async functions

```
Result1 result1 = await getResult1();
Result2 result2 = await getResult2();
doSomething(result1, result2);
```

Ideally I would hope that the compiler analyzes my method sees that `getResult2()` does not depend on the results of `getResult1()` and compiles this to code that schedules both to run simultaneously, awaiting the results of both before continuing.

**Question 1:** Is that what happens?

**Question 2:** If not, how do I make that happen assuming that `Result1` and `Result2` share no base type and I therefore cannot use `Task.WhenAll()`

Comment: In .NET "share no base type" is very unusual.  Are you returning pointer types?

Comment: @BenVoigt I mean other than `object`...I could of course box and unbox but that seems like the non-idiomatic way to go

Comment: `async-await` is about asynchrony and not parallelism.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is that what happens?

No.  `await` simply means, more or less, "don't continue executing code until the following task has completed".

> how do I make that happen

Start both tasks first, then await until they are both done:

```
var firstTask = getResult1();
var secondTask = getResult2();
await Task.WhenAll(firstTask, secondTask);
doSomething(firstTask.Result, secondTask.Result);
```

Comment: `WhenAll` won't work here since the return types are different, right?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Why won't it?  The results of the call to `await` aren't all that useful; but we don't need it anyway, since we have the tasks themselves.  If were didn't store the tasks and tried to grab the results from the call to `WhenAll` then we'd need to deal with that.

Comment: Like in Daniels answer you could just await when passing the parameters to the doSomething-method call.

Comment: oh I thought there wasn't an overload available. There is.

Comment: @user2674389 Sure.  There are tons of ways in which you can adjust it; it's simply a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Just for completeness sake - there's no language feature that does what I want it to do automatically right?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer What, you mean take items that you have specifically said must be run in a given order, and execute them out of order, no.  That's not possible.  If you want to not specify that they must be done in a given order to begin with, that's easy, I've showed you one of many possible ways to do that.  But yes, you will need to actually change the code if you want the behavior to change.

Comment: Right, there's nothing strictly preventing the compiler from doing what I'm asking for (as it would in many functional languages). It just seems like that's simply not a feature of C# yet. I just want to make sure that hasn't been implemented in some other feature.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer I'm failing to see what language feature you're expecting to be added.  There are already more than enough features to do what you want, even to do it quite easily.  The point of task based programming is that you specify the constraints.  Such and such can't be run until these other tasks finish.  You added a constraint that you didn't want, namely the starting of the second task being a continuation of the completion of the first. The solution is merely to remove that constraint, and only specify the one that you want, namely that `doSomething` needs both to have been completed.

Comment: Well in many languages the compiler would analyze the function, see that there are no dependencies between that two awaited blocks and compile to a version where both would run simultaneously. Yes, I understand that this might be surprising to many C# developers who frequently rely on side-effects but something that does this would be quite useful. As it stands it seems that `await` is just a glorified `task.Wait()`

Comment: No `await` is a glorified `.ContinueWith(` that reuses the old SynchronizationContext with all the code that happens after the `await` being passed in as the argument for the function. So you basicly did `getResult1().ContinueWith(() => getResult2(). ContinueWith(() => doSomething(result1, result2)));` You explicitly said "Do this, wait for the result, then do this, wait for the result, then do the last function", so the compiler can't optimize it away because it would be removing your explicit instructions not to do them in parallel.

Comment: You specifically went out of your way to *add* a dependency.  That's *what await is there for*.  If you don't want that dependency then you don't need a new feature to detect that you added a dependency that you shouldn't have, so that it can be removed, you only need to not add the dependency in the first place.  As Scott mentioned, `await` is quite different from `Wait` in that it is asynchronous, not synchronous.  It is very much just a `ContinueWith` that takes care of configuring the continuation for you.

Answer (score 4):

1. No, in your code you are waiting for the first result before starting the second operation.
2. First start both tasks, then await them:

   ```
   Task<Result1> task1 = getResult1();
   Task<Result2> task2 = getResult2();
   doSomething(await task1, await task2);
   ```